# Solve tasks in PHP and then redirect to another PHP file

Tags: php, variables, redirect, task

So im currently programming a register form, which passes variables with the entered informations to another php file through POST. Well, im performing some checks in this PHP file and whould like to pass the variables after that to the next register form on another php site.

Is this somehow possible ?

I will be thankfull for every answer i get!

-english is not my main language.

Comment: "on another php site"? on a different domain? different server?

Comment: Dont do this! What stops any attacker from just posting to your second page directly? Allways do the processing stuff in the same request as your validation!

Comment: @ToBe .. yeah i totatly didnt think of that. Thanks ! Ill simply do the checks on the same page where the input is located.

Comment: But: How can i get the variables from the "input-page" to my "next-page" @MarcB located on the same server securely ?- 
-Sessions ?
or can i somehow accomplish this through POST ?

Comment: Just include the file via "require" and run it. You might want to learn about functions if you didnt already. Then just require any php file with functions in it that you need and execute them when needed and where needed.

Comment: @ToBe ohh so variables which already have a value are automatically "included" when i use a require? lets say on "page1.php" i have $name="joe" and i require "page1.php" in "page2.php" . Does "page2.php" know that $name is "joe" ?   -Thanks again for your time

Comment: Yes they are, but even better way is to transmit them to a function via it's function parameters. This works with any function in any "required" PHP file.

Comment: So i could write a function called checkThem(username, password, email) and give the function the parameters and maybe "wait" for the return value? .. in Java you can return "OK";   is something similiar possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send informtaion using [cURL](https://php.net/curl)

Code example from http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post
    //extract data from the post
    extract($_POST);

```
//set POST variables
$url = 'http://domain.com/get-post.php';
$fields = array(
                        'lname' => urlencode($last_name),
                        'fname' => urlencode($first_name),
                        'title' => urlencode($title),
                        'company' => urlencode($institution),
                        'age' => urlencode($age),
                        'email' => urlencode($email),
                        'phone' => urlencode($phone)
                );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Keep in mind though that this is NOT an advisable solution for your problem of validating on one page and processing on another! Cant stress this enough. DO NOT DO THIS. (Other than that, cUrl is fine)